# In 5E World of Warcraft, does the Monk's Superior Martial Arts allow one attack vs every enemy in the area of effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, homebrew

[In the World of Warcraft 5e conversion](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16TLUl7Jf1HYp_h-snPZhz_TMZpQ0bM6A/view) (v3.3 by Djmove & Arrius Nideal), the Windwalker Monk's 'Superior Martial Arts' states:

> As an action, you may spend 2 Ki and deal your unarmed damage as an area of effect (expending any number of attacks). You may choose to make it a 5-foot-burst around you (Hurricane Kick), a 10-foot cone (Fists of Fury), or a 15-foot line (Flying Serpent Kick).

Does this mean the Monk makes a separate attack roll vs every target in the area of effect?

It also goes on to say:

> This action counts as if you made an unarmed attack strike for the purposes of your Martial Arts feature and Flurry of Blows ability.

Does that mean no matter how many attack rolls you make during the Superior Martial Arts attack, it still counts as having made one attack (out of however many you might be entitled to as part of an Attack action) and you still get to make an Extra Attack (if you have it) plus the bonus unarmed strike from Martial Arts?

Comment: This may be a good question to direct to the maintainers of the WoW conversion (and post as a self-answer, if you hear back from them).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This (homebrew) ability is written in a style quite unlike how the first party 5e content is written. I can't find a definition of what "(expending any number of attacks)" is meant to mean.

> Does this mean the Monk makes a separate attack roll vs every target in the area of effect?

As written, no. They just deal the damage with no attack rolls or saves. It sounds to me like it intends to mean "make an attack roll against (any or all) creatures in the area"

> you still get to make an Extra Attack (if you have it)

No, because you are not making the Attack action

> plus the bonus unarmed strike from Martial Arts?

It's unclear. You are not using the Attack action, so it should probably be clarified to

> This action counts as if you made an unarmed attack strike, as part of the Attack action, for the purposes of your Martial Arts feature and Flurry of Blows ability.

or, if "expending any number of attacks" means "make an attack roll against (any or all) creatures in the area"

> These unarmed attacks count as if they were made as part of the Attack action for the purposes of your Martial Arts feature and Flurry of Blows ability.

If that is the case, you can use a bonus action to make one unarmed attack, or use a bonus action and a Ki point to make two unarmed attacks